# Настройка пути к папке сайта на WinSCP

Tags: linux, windows, веб-программирование, файловая-система, winscp

Каким образом происходит настройка на WinSCP ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtplr6LYXLs - 3:21 - 5:00 )
(какие пункты меню надо нажать и где ввести данные)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Новое соединение?

Comment: Кажется, что нет (судя по содержимому окна должно быть как на видео как на Forklift) @KoVadim

Comment: как по мне, то второе окно в вопросе эквивалентно окну в видео.

Comment: @KoVadim а Local path чему эквивалентно?

Comment: нажмите кнопку Ещё. Там откроется меню, в дереве слева выберите "каталоги". там все есть.

Comment: @KoVadim а Base URL не нашел - подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: если я все правильно понимаю, то для нормальной работы scp оно не нужно.